# how do I write a query when there are multiple conditions to consider?

Tags: mysql

I have a table where a user is assigned tasks.  They may have 1 line in the table or as many as 5 - there's no max or min - it's random.  If a user has completed all of their tasks, their email needs to be removed from an email list. The problem is that a user may have one task or 2, 3, etc.  I cannot write a simple query that looks for their ID in the task field since it will find them even if they have only completed 1 task.  So, I need to write a query that only finds their email if all tasks are completed.

Example table:

UserID-----task
1----------0

2----------0

3----------1

3----------0

3----------0

4----------1

So, as you can see, user 1 only has one task, but user 3 has 3 tasks.

If I use this query, User 3 will be removed from list even though he still has tasks to complete:

```
SELECT userID from table_name
where task = 1
```

My actual query is more complex than this, but how would I write a query that finds any userID who has completed all tasks?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
SELECT userID from table_name
where task = 1
and task != 0
```

Comment: can you illustrate what your table structure is,

Comment: which is task completed `0` or `1`?

Comment: task completed = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT userID
FROM table_name
GROUP BY userID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN task = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

The `HAVING` clause will aggregate each user's records and count the number of times which an unfinished task (indicated by `task=0`) occurs.  You can replace the logic with `task <> 1` if there could be other task codes besides 0 and 1.

Comment: select DISTINCT(u.email) as email 
from jos_users u, keyperson k
where (k.kp1 = u.id and k.check1 = 1)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN (k.kp1 = u.id and k.check1 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0

Comment: make that select DISTINCT(u.email) as email 
from jos_users u, keyperson k
where (k.kp1 = u.id and k.check1 = 1)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN (k.kp1 = u.id and k.check1 = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0.

Comment: No, I won't change my query because what you are suggesting in the above comments does not agree with the information in your question.